# Flutter Bottom Overflowed by 143 pixels

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow

Im trying to build a sushi app, but when i rotate my phone, theres black and yellow line, it says "Bottom Overflowed by 143 pixels"

[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKbn6.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoj16.png)

I tried some tutorial on youtube, but then the result is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SingleChildScrollView then it solve your problem but if Column/Row widget contain any widget which has infinite height then your screen show a blank screen. So please check is there any Expanded/Flexible widget in your column widget.

Better paste your full code so that I can identify the problem

UPDATED:

I saw your code I think this is the problem

```
  Expanded( // Use SizedBox and set fixed height
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: foodMenu.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => FoodTile(
                food: foodMenu[index],
                onTap: () => navigateToFoodDetails(index),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

if you want whole screen scroll then
--> wrap your Column with SingleChildScrollView
--> Remove Expanded and use SizedBox with a fixed height

Comment: here is the code: https://pastebin.com/kv1aM94U

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

> Bottom Overflowed by 143 pixels

Means there's content below the screen with the height size of 143 pixels.

You need a strategy for landscape mobile view. Either make a different design that fits the whole screen or wrap your `Column` with a `SingleChildScrollView` widget for it to become scrollable and the overflowing content should be draggable into view.

---

**Edit:**

An `Expanded` widget inside a `SingleChildScrollView` with the default vertical scroll direction gives it an infinity height, causing the 'RenderBox was not laid out' error

> Usually, the issue is related to violation of box constraints, and it
> needs to be solved by providing more information to Flutter about how
> you’d like to constrain the widgets in question. You can learn more
> about how constraints work in Flutter on the [Understanding constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)
> page.
>
> The RenderBox was not laid out error is often caused by one of two
> other errors:
>
> - 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height'
> - ‘An InputDecorator…cannot have an unbounded width'

**Solution**
Give you `ListView` a known height.

Replace `Expanded` with a `SizedBox` then assign the height.

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 250, // Modify to your preference.
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: foodMenu.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => FoodTile(
      food: foodMenu[index],
      onTap: () => navigateToFoodDetails(index),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: the result is blank

Comment: Are there errors printed in console?

Comment: there is no errors

Comment: It gives me a 'RenderBox was not laid out' error. I've update the answer.